# Updating the data from two table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to update some values in the table by multiplying the `t1` values to `t2` values. Here is the query I wrote to update the data. For some reasons it's taking long time to update the values. Can I have some simplified query to update the same data to improve the performance of query?

```sql
update dm_digital_media.dim_dummy sub
set sub.SUBS_ONE_TIME_TOTAL_USD = sub.SUBS_ONE_TIME_TOTAL_LOCAL_CURR * nvl(exch.exchange_rate,1) 
from dm_digital_media.dim_dummy sub1
inner join dm_digital_media.rate_dim exch on exch.exchange_source = sub1.currency
where sub.START_DATE < '2018-01-01'
  and exch.exchange_target = 'USD'
  and exch.begin_effect_date = '2018-01-01'
  and exch.exchange_period = 'Monthly';
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls try below SQL? I modified it a bit with CTE.

```
with exch as (
select exchange_source,nvl(exch.exchange_rate,1) exchange_rate from dm_digital_media.rate_dim exch where  exch.exchange_target = 'USD' and exch.begin_effect_date = '2018-01-01' and exch.exchange_period = 'Monthly'
)
update dm_digital_media.dim_dummy sub set sub.SUBS_ONE_TIME_TOTAL_USD = sub.SUBS_ONE_TIME_TOTAL_LOCAL_CURR * exchange_rate
from dm_digital_media.dim_dummy sub1 
inner join exch on exch.exchange_source = sub1.currency 
where sub.START_DATE < '2018-01-01' ;
```